# Find cov$(y_t,y_{t-k})$ for the random walk $y_t=y_{t-1}+v_{t}$ where $v_t \sim N(0,\sigma^{2}_{v})$

Tags: statistics, random-walk

Given the random walk model $y_t=y_{t-1}+v_{t}$ where $v_t$ are iid $N(0,\sigma^{2}_{v})$, I want to find an expression for cov$(y_t,y_{t-k})$.

I've had a look at past posts, but they all seem to show 
cov$(y_t,y_{t+h})=\text{var}(y_{t})=t\sigma^{2}_{v}$ for what I assume is $h>0$, and my result below is different.

*My attempt:*

Let $k>0$. Then 
\begin{align}
\text{cov}(y_t,y_{t-k})=&\text{cov}(y_{t-1}+v_{t},y_{t-k})\\
=&\text{cov}(y_{t-1},y_{t-k})\\
&\vdots\\
=&\text{cov}(y_{t-k},y_{t-k})\\
=&\text{var}(y_{t-k})\\
=&(t-k)\sigma_{v}^{2}
\end{align}
where the second inequality holds because $y_{t-k}$ does not depend on the future value $v_{t}$.

So the covariance between lags $h$ apart does not depend on the time interval $h$, but ones $k$ apart do. How can that be?

Comment: Should we assume that $v_t$ and $v_k$ are independent for $t \neq k$?

Comment: @oneloop Hello, yes sorry I forgot to add that in

Comment: Are you sure that other posts show that $cov(y_t, y_{t+h}) = t \sigma_v^2$? From symmetry I would expect $cov(y_t, y_{t+h}) = h\sigma_v^2$

Comment: @oneloop Here's one example: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/99796/how-can-i-show-that-a-random-walk-is-not-covariance-stationary

Comment: Now I'm even more confused. In the post that you linked they're trying to prove covariance-stationarity, the definition of which is that it should NOT depend on $t$, but only on the difference between the two points in time, i.e. $h$. I'm going to bed.

Comment: Oh wait they're proving that it's not covariance-stationary, so it should depend on $t$. Anyway off to sleep.

Comment: I suppose you mean that the $v_t$ are independent with $N(0,\sigma_v^2)$ distribution?

Comment: @Math1000 That's correct yes, sorry I'll add that in

Comment: You know cov$(y_t,y_{t+h})$ and you are asking for cov$(y_t,y_{t-k})$, right? Well, simply use the former with $(t-k,k)$ for $(t,h)$.

Comment: @Did Aha thank you! Is it ok to write cov$(y_{t-h},y_{t})=\text{cov}(y_{t},y_{t+h})$ because this is just relabelling terms that are $h$ apart and has nothing to do with covariance stationarity? I've been confusing myself thinking it was the latter. Also is my initial proof correct or have I just fluked the right answer?

Comment: The process is **not** stationary hence, as I said, one should replace $t$ by $t+h$ in the formula.

Comment: @Did Oh so cov$(y_{t},y_{t+h})=t\sigma^{2} \implies \text{cov}(y_{t-h},y_{t})=(t-h)\sigma^{2}_{v}$ just using relabelling and not stationarity?

Comment: Yes, for every $t\geqslant h\geqslant0$.

Comment: @Did I see, thank you very much! Would you like to post your comment as an answer so I can mark the question as solved? Lastly, in my proof is the second inequality an acceptable jump to make?

Comment: You might want instead to write down an answer yourself and post it, this is actually recommended by the site.